# Unable to modify object by another - runtime Error 91

Tags: vba, class, object, combobox, controls

Let's say I have a user form with two combo boxes created at runtime. First combo sources items from A1:A2 (Fruits, Vegetables). I want the second combo to source either from B1:B2 (Apple,Orange) or from C1:C2 (Carrot,Tomato) deppending what user chose in first combo. Below my class named "FoodClass"

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents MyCombo1 As MSForms.ComboBox
Public WithEvents MyCombo2 As MSForms.ComboBox

Public Sub DrawCombo1(oParent)
Set MyCombo1 = oParent.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "Combo1", True)
     With MyCombo1
        .Top = 20
        '(...) setting position
        .RowSource = "A1:A2" 'Fruits;Vegetables
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub DrawCombo2(oParent)
    Set MyCombo2 = oParent.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "Combo2", True)
     With MyCombo2
        '(seting position)
     End With
End Sub

Public Sub MyCombo1_Change()'When user chose from combo 1... 
    If MyCombo1.Value = "Fruits" Then MyCombo2.RowSource = "B1:B2" 'Apple;Orange
    If MyCombo1.Value = "Vegetables" Then MyCombo2.RowSource = "C1:C2"'Carrot;Tomato
End Sub
```

Then there is my code in user form:

```
Option Explicit

Public ComboBox1 As FoodClass
Public Combobox2 As FoodClass

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Set ComboBox1 = New FoodClass
    Call ComboBox1.DrawCombo1(UserForm)

    Set Combobox2 = New FoodClass
    Call Combobox2.DrawCombo2(UserForm)

End Sub
```

Each time user changes the first combobox Error 91 appears. How can I modify one object by another?

Comment: why do you need VBA ? you can have 2 List Boxes, and use `Indirect` on the second one

Comment: You have two combos in the class FoodClass and you create two instances of FoodClass, but each instance has only one combo initialized. The second one is not set. That is why the error 91 appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `UserForm_Initialize` create just one instance of `FoodClass` so this instance will have both combo boxes initialized:

```
dim food as FoodClass
Set food = New FoodClass
call food.DrawCombo1(UserForm)
call food.DrawCombo2(UserForm)
```

*Note: Instead of `UserForm` the keyword `Me` can be used inside of the UserForm class. `Me` refers to current instance of the UserForm.*

```
call food.DrawCombo1(Me)
```

Comment: Working! :) Thank you. This forum is amazing. You just made someone's life easier somewhere in southern Poland. When I will finish my macro about 130 people in my company will get a (hopefully great) tool :) Much appreciated! :)